Androidバージョン「8」で「推奨レベルを超えるまで音量を上げますか？大音量で長時間聴き続けると、聴力を損なう恐れがあります」警告ウィンドウを表示されないようにするには？
Androidバージョン「8」で、一定期間経過後に自動的に音量ダウン後、「推奨レベルを超えるまで音量を上げますか？大音量で長時間聴き続けると、聴力を損なう恐れがあります」警告ウィンドウを表示されないようにするには？
試したこと
・「開発者向けオプション」リストの中に「絶対音量を無効にする」だけがあり、「高音量警告を無効にする」オプションはありませんでした。「絶対音量を無効にする」を有効にしましたが、効果ありませんでした。
・TermuxというアプリをGoogle Playストアからダウンロードしようとしたのですが、似たようなアプリがたくさんありどれかわかりませんでした。
・パソコンで検索するとTermuxが出てくるが、AndroidのGoogle Playストアからではなぜか見つからない。
・Termux、代替として「UserLAnd」アプリをインストール後、「su」と入力してスーパーユーザーのプロンプトが表示され「setprop audio.safemedia.bypass true」と入力したら「bash:set prop command not found」
・PlayストアからSolid Explorerファイルマネージャーをダウンロードし、rootディレクトリに移動しステムディレクトリに移動し、build.propファイルを開こうとすると、アクセスが拒否されました

今回に限らず、質問が当サイトで扱う 話題の範囲 として妥当かを意識してから投稿して欲しいです。今回の質問は単にAndroid端末の設定・操作方法を問うもので、個人的にはプログラミングの話題からは外れているように思います。

「試したこと」に対して補足しておくと… アプリで設定された推奨バージョンに満たない端末の場合、Playストアでは該当アプリが検索結果に出てこない仕様だったと思います。アプリの詳細ページを見れば「Android 要件」が確認できます。 / UserLAnd は WSL のような「Linuxのエミュレータ」アプリなので、端末自体の設定は変更できません。 / 端末が root 化されていない状態では、システム領域のファイルを書き換えることはできません。

まあ普通に考えてこの手の警告は、出すべきであると誰かが（ Google なり Apple なりが）判断した結果出ているのであるわけなので、出てしかるべきである、と考えましょう。システムの発行する警告ダイアログを１アプリケーションの都合で無理やり出さなくすることができるのであれば、それは悪意ある攻撃アプリケーションにも可能なわけで、それではセキュリティ的によろしくないです。出さなくする方法を教えろ＝セキュリティホールを教えろとも読めるので、こういう場所ではたとえ手順を知っている人がいても情報は出てこないでしょう。
# 警告なしに音量を大きくできた結果として鼓膜に障害を負った、責任と賠償を・・・ってなるくらいなら、警告が出てくるほうがマシって考えないんですか？
んで @re9 さんの他の質問と同様、この質問もおそらくXY問題です。それも WXY なレベル。
- 警告を出さなくすること (Y) が目的なのではなくて
- 音量を上げること (X) が目的のようにも一見読めますが
- 真にやりたいこと (W) は全く別、なのでは？

目的は、音量を自動的に下げさせないことです
